# Is it technically possible to take a screenshot of a website programmatically?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, screenshot

Do you think is technically possible to take a screeshot of a website programmatically?

I would like to craft a scheduled Python task that crawls a list of websites taking an homepage screenshot of them.

Do you think is technically feasible or do you know third party website that offer a service like that (`Input: url --> Output: screenshot`) ?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking for functionality like what http://www.browsershots.org offers? Source code available at http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/

Comment: @birryree you should answer instead of commenting :) i think it's a good answer

Comment: I agree with samy - it answers the question after all! :)

Answer (score 15):

Are you looking for functionality like what [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) offers?

Source code available at [Google Code/Browsershots](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/).

Comment: +1 - didn't know this was written with Python and it does the required job exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can check [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) (only OS X) and [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) (Linux) and this [post](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB901.html) (use PyQt and WebKit).

Comment: webkit2png also works on GNU/Linux, see this post: http://gfdsa.gfdsa.org/2012/08/15/making-web-pages-screenshots-with-webkit2png-flash-included/

Answer (score 2):

I used selenium and PhantomJS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://anyurl.com")
driver.save_screenshot("/path/to/folder")
```

be sure to place the PhantomJS executable in your $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

How about pyGTK

```
import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

Comment: ImageMagick is just a generic library of functions for doing work on images.  That would be like answering the question, "How can I implement FFT in C#?" and you answering "Oh, you can use something in the Maths class for that".

Comment: In what way does ImageMagick provide the ability to render HTML into an image?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly technically possible.

You would probably have to render the HTML directly onto an image file (or more likely, onto an in-memory bitmap that's written to an image file once completed).

I don't know any libraries to do this for you (apart from a modified WebKit, perhaps)... but there's certainly websites that do this.

Of course, this is a bit more involved than just opening the page in a browser on a machine and taking a screenshot programatically, but the result would likely be better if you don't care about the result from a specific browser.