# Can I take a snapshot of a website from the command line?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, image, bash, fortran

I am writing documentation for a website  [database](http://ebi-forecast.igb.uiuc.edu) interface. Is it possible to write a script that, when executed, takes the most recent snapshot of the website and saves it as an image file?

*note: I am using the tags ruby, bash, and python since those are the languages used in our group (along with R and FORTRAN; for sport, I'll set a 100 point bounty If anyone can post a FORTRAN solution).*

**update:** as @birryree notes, a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940098/is-it-technically-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-programmatically/3940169#3940169) provides the answer. Considering the FORTRAN offer is just for sport, perhaps this is a duplicate?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940098/is-it-technically-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-programmatically/3940169#3940169. But no idea about Fortran!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WkHTMLtoPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) has binaries which also convert web pages to images using webkit's renderer.

Comment: Something similar has also been done with Qt and Webkit in Python: http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB901.html

Comment: excellent. easy to apt-get install and use! thanks

Comment: the program and command are 'wkhtmltopdf' (not *2pdf)

Comment: @David: thanks for the correction, it was typed in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful -- [an interesting Python project which processes a queue of URLs and exports the browser screenshots to your server](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/).

Comment: useful and relevant yet overkill, neat program though

Answer (score 2):

Would it be okay to take a snapshot of a web page and save it as an HTML file with images? Because that's trivial.

`wget -m -p http://www.example.com/example.html`

Comment: +1 for useful code, and the fact that this gets me one step closer if there is something like html2jpg

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with selenium.  First set up seleniumrc. Then using any of the language apis, use the captureScreenshot() method.  Here is an example in java:

http://www.cloudtesting.com/blog/2009/06/24/capturing-screen-shots-of-browsers-with-selenium-and-cloud-testing-part-1/

Note that selenium will need a display to render to, but you can also use a virtual frame buffer like Xvfb on Linux (probably installed by default)

I would also recommend the seleniumIDE firefox plugin as it can basically write the code for you in any language.

Answer (score 2):

[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) (command-line) does a fine job.

```
CutyCapt --url=http://www.example.org --out=example.png
```

Comment: looks nice, but this returns a blank file, tested also on www.google.com

Comment: @David, well, there must be some problem for your particular environement (OS, etc), but this sure works here: $ CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.com --out=google.png

Comment: I got it to work, but have to specify the entire url e.g. ./CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.com/ --out=google.png. Thanks!