# How do I screen capture a URL with PIL?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a server process that will allow you to enter a URL, then every 30 min ping that URL and capture it as an image. Is this possible with a combination of something like CURL, urllib2 and PIL?

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940098/is-it-technically-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Curl, urllib2, etc., grab the HTML code for a web page. But a page doesn't *look like* anything on its own. Instead, a browser uses that code and renders a web page according to its own internal rules of how that code should be used. And, of course, each browser renders the page slightly differently.

In other words, you can't take a snapshot of a page without having a web browser to generate the page to take the snapshot of.

If you're feeling very ambitious, you can create your own custom, scriptable page renderer by using the rendering engine from the browser of your choice -- they all make the rendering engine [a separate component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browser_engines) that you can work with separately. IE's is called "Trident", Firefox's is called "Gecko", Chrome's is "WebKit", etc.

Otherwise you'll want to just do some sort of UI scripting, like you might do with [iOpus](http://www.iopus.com/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Selenium is scriptable with python, so that's one for you right there.

**EDIT**

[Here you go](http://www.cloudtesting.com/blog/2009/06/24/capturing-screen-shots-of-browsers-with-selenium-and-cloud-testing-part-1/). That looks pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageGrab](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm) can be used to take a screenshot on windows. However, you can't do this purely using CURL, urllib2 and PIL, because you will have to render the web site. The easiest would probably be to [open the website in a browser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) and grab a screenshot.

Comment: I'm assuming this is mostly used in a GUI environment, not purely as a command line process?

Comment: Yes, like I stated, the ImageGrab module only works under Windows. This method also requires a browser, so no, this would not work as a command line process.